# Is there any way I can reply to messages inside JSQMessagesViewController?

Tags: swift, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I am looking at what WhatsApp and they have gesture recognizer which enables the user to reply to a message within the chat if he long presses a message. Is such feature available on JSQMessagesViewController. I can't find anything in the source code that would enable me to do that. 
Please advise any alternative.

Comment: `jsqmessagesviewcontroller` is deprecated. You may have to switch to some other.

Comment: I know that, but I am using it in an old project

Comment: Hi bibscy, did you get the solution ?

Comment: No i have not found one

Comment: There was some activity here: https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController/issues/2121